# rust: defining a ToStr for fmt

Tags: rust

I want `fmt!("%?", obj)` to call a method on my object to format the result. I tried implementing the `ToStr` and `Repr` traits, but neither seemed to work. Here's my test code:

```
pub struct Element {
    name: ~str,
}

impl ToStr for Element {
    pub fn to_str(&self) -> ~str {
        fmt!("<%s>", self.name)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let e = Element{name: ~"root"};
    io::println(fmt!("e: %?", e));
}
```

It prints:

```
e: {name: ~"root"}
```

I'd expect it to print:

```
e: <root>
```

I'm using Rust 0.6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`%?` is a structural formatter, and this is unlikely to change.

The only current method to print the `ToStr` representation is to actually call `to_str`, e.g.:

```
fn main() {
    let e = Element{name: ~"root"};
    println(fmt!("e: %s", e.to_str()));
}
```

(There's currently vague plans and some half-implementations for supporting overloading the formatting specifiers (except for `%?`), but nothing in the compiler yet.)